# Replace this Slime In Scene

Tags: modeling, fluid-simulation, tracking

I've just dived into Blender over the last few weeks in order to gain some skills to solve a filmic problem. I of course did the Donut tutorial and really enjoyed the process.

Here's my question:

I want to build a photo real model of slime to composite over the practical slime used on a short film set as it is "underwhelming". I've attached a frame grab from the film. The camera tracks the slime trail from the doorway, this is close to the end of the shot. I've tried to build models using metaballs and other shapes but I really can't seem to nail it. A see through organic shape that reflects light with air bubbles (particles?) could do it but I can't seem to get there. Might anyone point me in a direction..tutorial, etc that could be helpful. I've watched several like the Beer tutorial but can't seem to find an answer.[image]

Comment: Suggestion. See Fluid Simulation (FS) examples.  Please show some of your Blender Work as a Blender screen capture.  Search Viscosity in relation to FS.  I see fluid in your current image on floor.  I do not know what part is the most important.  Know that getting particular details in FS is not easy.  You may need hybrid solution or compose a few FS. If the slime is only on the floor please state so, or annotate so. The bright vertical line could be an unimportant corner or slime as well.

Comment: TY for the quick response. The fluid on the floor doesn't move. It was movie slime product..transparent goo with air bubbles. That's the part that needs to be replaced and focused tracked etc. with something a bit more visual. It could just be a translucent/transparent model with a bit of glow.

Comment: Fluid Simulation (FS) requires more compute power and a learning effort.  FS will produce a mesh, if that is acceptable to you.  You may also want to search examples of Blender Users putting air bubbles in to a model with composition or boolean operators.  Is the desired result a still image or motion video?  You can answer the question in your original question and refer the reader if that suits you.

Comment: Unfortunately for you this shot wasn't filmed with tracking in mind.  It would help to have distinct markers so that the tracking algorithm can follow them around the frame (which would then be removed using more vfx magic).  The issue right now is getting an accurate enough camera solve to match up your new model such that it isn't obviously added after the fact.

Comment: Atomic..the shot is a moving pov tracking shot...

Comment: Allen you are correct..but the tracking solve I have out of Blender isn't terrible...I'll keep tweaking. I think I had a better solve inside Fusion. On Star Wars projects and others we had lots of handheld without marks tracked perfectly but this shot is a bit wonky as it was actually a grab and the DOF is shallow and the focus a bit goosey. It was meant to be an in camera practical EFX but I thought I'd take a stab at punching up the shot for him. Low budget passion project for a friend...sometimes things move too fast but better than not moving at all.